# php exec command with azure cli always return null

Tags: php, azure, apache, exec

On a server Apache which runs PHP, I have a command which always return null.

> exec("az storage container exists --account-name $accountName
> --account-key $key --name $containeurName", $output);

I modified the sudoers file but it didn't change anything:

> www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/az

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exec($your_command, $output, $error_code)` and see what `$error_code` contains. It may just be because `az` isn't in the PATH env variable in PHP.

Try to put the full path to your executable, typically something like this:

```php
<?php

// A default path in case "which az" doesn't work.
define('AZ_DEFAULT_PATH', '/usr/bin/az');

// Find the path to az with the "which" command.
$az_path = exec('which az');
if ($az_path === false) {
  $az_path = AZ_DEFAULT_PATH;
}

// Sanitize your variables to avoid shell injection and build the command.
$cmd = $az_path .
       "storage container exists --account-name $accountName " .
       "--account-key $key --name $containeurName";

$last_line = exec($cmd, $full_output, $error_code);

// Then check if $last_line !== false and check $error_code to see
// what happened.
var_export([
  '$cmd' => $cmd,
  '$last_line' => $last_line,
  '$full_output' => $full_output,
  '$error_code' => $error_code,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it returns : '$cmd' => 'mycmd',\n  '$last_line' => '',\n  '$full_output' => \n array (\n  ),\n  '$error_code' => 1

Comment: Difficult to say but I’m a bit surprised with the value of $cmd containing `mycmd`. What does the error code 1 mean? Does your executable have any doc about it? Try running some other easy commands and see if they work.

Comment: Hi, mycmd is just to say that it returns the cmd properly. For the error code 1.i have no idea what it means.

Comment: Unfortunately I never used the `/usr/bin/az` CLI so I don't know what error code 1 means. You might need to search in Microsoft's documentation or Google around. Sorry I can't help.